# Module not found: Package path ./react is not exported from package E:\NextApp\portfolio_website-main\portfolio_website-main\node_modules\next-auth

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth

I can't import SessionProvider from Next-Auth. While importing it's showing this error.

"Module not found: Package path ./react is not exported from package E:\NextApp\portfolio_website-main\portfolio_website-main\node_modules\next-auth"

here is my code:(_app.js)

```
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react"

export default function App({Component, pageProps: { session, ...pageProps }}) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      <Component {...pageProps}/>
    </SessionProvider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Try unistalling and reinstalling the package

Comment: I have tried this at the first place.

Answer (score 2):

you might be on v3 where `next-auth/client` is still in use. Either import that or run `npm i next-auth@beta` to use v4

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and manage to fix it. Basically, There is a bad version of Next Auth out there so to avoid it, remove the `^` symbol before the version number in your `package.json` file

You can see the warning [in the documentation here](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/upgrade-v4).

So the next-auth line in your package.json should read like this:

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "next-auth": "4.0.0-beta.4",
    ...
  }
}
```

Instead of this:

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "next-auth": "^4.0.0-beta.4",
    ...
  }
}
```

After you have done that make sure to run `npm i` or `yarn` to ensure the packages are updated.

That should fix your issue although I am now getting a `getSessionAndUser is not a function` Type error